# Java enters if-block on FALSE

Tags: java

This is by far the most peculiar problem I've run across in programming. Java enters an `if-block` even though the `if-expression`, a mere boolean variable set to `false`, is `false`.

I've not modified any code or variable values during the debug session, even terminated and re-launched the application multiple times without touching anything. How can this be possible?!

[image: False is evaluated to true by Java.]

Running Java 1.8.0_45.

*Edit*: Even `!phalse` steps into the block. Clean & Rebuild doesn't help.

Comment: Rebuild sources maybe?

Comment: Your source doesn't match your compiled class.

Comment: Try `!phalse` and check what it does

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The only thing your debugger shows is, that the condition of your if statement evaluates to `false` and that inside the if clause the condition is still `false`.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: What kind of IDE do you use?

Comment: @GameDroids ...and that the execution steps into the if-block even though the condition is false.

Comment: @nguyentt Eclipse Photon on a Mac.

Comment: can you post some more code ?

Comment: I think the problem came from the JDK 1.8_45. This build is quite not stable. But I'm not sure!

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and rebuilding again. Also see if changing the variable help (phalse anyways isnt a good name)....

Comment: I'd go with rustyx on this one. Suspect the breakpoint lines aren't actually matching your source's. Is your exception actually being thrown?

Comment: @Mena Yes, the exception is thrown. Project clean & rebuild doesn't change anything. Checking for `!phalse` still steps into the block.

Comment: Also see if you can use Boolean instead of boolean and set field to TRUE

Comment: If your code is present in a jar, rebuild and export the jar again.

Comment: Add some printing to your block not only this exception, so we can be sure.

Comment: What you see(code) is not what it is exectuted(runtime) rebuild/redeploy re everything - even restart pc if needed. ;)

Comment: This is unlikely to be helpful once solved, if, as I and others assume, the problem is due to the source being out-of-sync with the code (including the debugger). The problem appears to occur only in OP's computer, code, and IDE, and is only reproducible, according to the OP, there. An https://sscce.org would make me reverse my close vote (and be highly surprising).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
if(phale){
   System.out.println("Oh yeah im rly dunno how to handle if conditions");
   throw ...
}
```

You will see that there is no printout - and that will proof that what you see (code) is not what is beeing executed (runtime codebase).

Clean and reboot - if required delete by hand `classes` directory (if using maven) or `output` if eclipse plain java project.

Comment: You are right, there must have been a cached binary that was being executed. Thanks!